# Scaling down images with different widths in smaller parent div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to recreate a chat using images as the messages. The images are of different widths and are in a parent div with a fixed width of 500px. The images are however bigger than 500px, which means that if I scale them down with "max-width: 80%", they do scale down but all to the same width. How can I keep the different widths while scaling them down? Can I achieve that with flexbox? Or with table?

Edit: This is roughly what it should look like: [image]

Here's the snippet of the situation:

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 500px;
}
.chat {
  border: 2px solid #b7b7b7;
}
.chat .chat-header {
  width: 496px;
  margin-bottom: -2.5px;
  position: relative;
}
.chat .chat-history {
  padding: 2%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 700px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.message {
  max-width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 2px;
}
.float-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="chat">
      <div class="chat-header">
        <img class="chat-header" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1280x212"/>
      </div>
    <div class="chat-history">

      <div class="test">
        <img class="message float-right" src="https://via.placeholder.com/736x143" width="736" height="143" />
      </div>
        <div class="test">
          <img class="message" src="https://via.placeholder.com/530x384" width="530" height="384"/>
        </div>
      <div class="test">
        <img class="message float-right" src="https://via.placeholder.com/591x140" width="591" height="140" />
      </div>

      <div class="test">
        <img class="message" src="https://via.placeholder.com/546x152" width="546" height="152" />
      </div>

      <div class="test">
        <img class="message float-right" src="https://via.placeholder.com/561x101" width="561" height="101" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img class="message float-right" src="https://via.placeholder.com/698x124" width="698" height="124" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <img class="message" src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x203" width="840" height="203" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img class="message" src="https://via.placeholder.com/824x141" width="824" height="141" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img class="message" src="https://via.placeholder.com/770x141" width="770" height="141" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <img class="message float-right" src="https://via.placeholder.com/748x139" width="748" height="139" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img class="message float-right" src="https://via.placeholder.com/725x85" width="725" height="85" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <img class="message" src="https://via.placeholder.com/812x197" width="812" height="197" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img class="message" src="https://via.placeholder.com/859x189" width="859" height="189" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <img class="message float-right" src="https://via.placeholder.com/740x140" width="740" height="140" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img class="message float-right" src="https://via.placeholder.com/596x125" width="596" height="125" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <img class="message" src="https://via.placeholder.com/857x109" width="857" height="109" />
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is making them all the same height not an option? In fact, are you even sure you know how you expect the image resizing to behave? I've read your question a few times now and it's still not clear. "How can I keep the different widths while scaling them down" - make the heights all the same thus the widths will vary. Done. I suspect this isn't what you want though. Is it?

Comment: I'm sorry – the way I phrased it was pretty unclear. I edited the original question and inserted an image of how I'd like it to look like.

Comment: There is no CSS solution to this. You need a script that will measure each image's width and give them a width relative to the widest one.

Answer (score -1):

Use several `:nth-child(expr)` presets with different `max-width`. `expr` should be some formula with `n` so you get repeated patterns of image scaling or some patterns that look random.

Example:

```
.message-container:nth-child(2n) .message {
  max-width: 60%;
}

.message-container:nth-child(2n+1) .message {
  max-width: 50%;
}

.message-container:nth-child(3n+2) .message {
  max-width: 40%;
}
```

Set `message-container` class to divs inside `chat-history` or use `.chat-history > div` instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child